# Oracle dynamic parameters error

Tags: c#, dapper

I got the function that returns me a `varchar2`.

I'm using dapper and I got a problem while executing this query.

```
OracleDynamicParameters DictionaryParams = new OracleDynamicParameters();

DictionaryParams.Add(name: "id", value: id,direction: ParameterDirection.Input);
DictionaryParams.Add(name: "Return_Value",oracleDbType: OracleDbType.Varchar2,direction: ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);

con.Execute("function_name", DictionaryParams, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

 string a;

 a = DictionaryParams.Get<string>("Return_Value");
```

And I got an Oracle error:

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: error  number  or value :character string buffer too small

I tried to give a size to a returning value but this didn't work, and I also tried to figure out but everything didn't worked.

Can someone take a look at this?

Comment: Have you tried uping the value for OracleDbType.Varchar2?

Comment: Could the error be in the procedure call itself?  If you call the procedure directly from sqlplus, does it work?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the max size of the varchar2.

Example:

parameters.Add("P_OUTPUT", dbType: OracleDbType.Varchar2, direction: ParameterDirection.Output, size: 1000);

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem originates from using Char which is a fixed length string.
Somewhere in your PL-SQL code you try to put a Char or varchar2 string of length N into a char of lengh M where M > N